# How can I pass an angularJS directive/component as an attribue to other directive/component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

My goal is simple, I have a `<modal></modal>` component in which I want to pass an `<login></login>`, a `<register></register>` and other components as an attribue, using the following syntax:

`<modal directive="<login></login>"</modal>`

but all I'm getting inside the modal template is `&lt;login&gt;&lt;/login&gt;`. My directive is being sanitized and not compiled.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possible approaches:

1) Use the ngTransclude directive on your modal to allow it's template to replace a section with whatever elements (including other directives) you nest inside the modal tags. Note that this is different than the directive option transclude:true

[Angular docs for ngTransclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)

2) Instead of passing in a directive as an attribute, how about an attribute that tells the modal directive whether to enable an instance of that directive inside it's own template?

```
<modal use-login="true" use-register="true"></modal>
```

inside modal template

```
<div>
  <login ng-if="enableLogin"></login>
  <register ng-if="enableRegister"></register>
</div>
```

modal js code

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  if (attrs.useLogin) { $scope.enableLogin = true; }
  if (attrs.useRegister) { $scope.enableRegister = true; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is how ui-boostrap been implemented: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal but it might be a bit overkill to implement it for your self, if you are not already using ui-bootstrap. It also comes with disadvantage having to use Controller.

I would prefer Daniel Nalbach's option 2 just for the sake of simplicity of the implementation unless you have a huge amount of different directives you want to use the modal with.